# (C++) Best way to serialize my database of customer?

Tags: c++, sql, database, qt, serialization

I'm currently doing a program for a Notary for storing his customers informations, and here's my concern:

**XML + Serialisation usage vs Vector (of Objects) + Serialisation usage vs SQL Databases.**

**Using Qt**, I would like to know which would be the best for storing clients, searching and modifying the clients?

I have a lots of textboxes and checkmarks (Names, adresses, Sellers informations, Buyers informations, etc).

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Binary or plaintext and most applications of XML serialization solve **very** different problems from most uses of SQL. What kind of scale are you looking at here, what kind of access and usage requirements? Concurrency, environment (server?), speed, data size, permissions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I'd go with an SQLite database. XML is great for interchange between programs or storage, but not the most efficient for searching. Vector serialization is not so easily documented. SQLite is well-known, embedded (no separate process needed), easy to search, and efficient for speed. I would consider that the best compromise for speed and self-documentation.

I'm assuming this is an application for one person's keeping of legally significant records.